# How to search for multiple substrings using text.find

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a Python beginner, so please forgive me if I'm not using the right lingo and if my code includes blatant errors.

I have text data (i.e., job descriptions from job postings) in one column of my data frame. I want to determine which job ads contain any of the following strings: bachelor, ba/bs, bs/ba.

The function I wrote doesn't work because it produces an empty column (i.e., all zeros). It works fine if I just search for one substring at a time. Here it is:

```
def requires_bachelor(text):    
    if text.find('bachelor|ba/bs|bs/ba')>-1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
df_jobs['bachelor']=df_jobs['description'].apply(requires_bachelor).map({True:1, False:0})
```

Thanks so much to anyone who is willing to help!

Comment: I'm not a python dev, but I'd go with regular expressions in your case. This might get you started https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html#:~:text=re.match()%20function%20of,it%20returns%20the%20match%20object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach. You were pretty close but you need to check for each of the items individually. If any of the available "Bachelor tags" exist, return true. Then instead of using `map({true:1, false:0})`, you can use `map(bool)` to make it a bit nicer. Good luck!

```py
import pandas as pd

df_jobs = pd.DataFrame({"name":["bob", "sally"], "description":["bachelor", "ms"]})
def requires_bachelor(text):
    return any(text.find(a) > -1 for a in ['bachelor', 'ba/bs','bs/ba']) # -1 if not found

df_jobs['bachelor']=df_jobs['description'].apply(requires_bachelor).map(bool)
```

Comment: Fantastic! I liked your solution the best and it worked really well. Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: Great to hear @isa_r! Please take the time to mark the solution as the answer to the question so the thread can be closed :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you are checking for a string `bachelor|ba/bs|bs/ba` in the list, Which I don't believe will exist in any case...

What I suggest you do is to check for all possible combinations in the IF, and join them with a or statement, as follows:

```
def requires_bachelor(text):    
    if text.find('bachelor')>-1 or text.find('ba/bs')>-1 or text.find('bs/ba')>-1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
df_jobs['bachelor']=df_jobs['description'].apply(requires_bachelor).map({True:1, False:0})
```

Comment: You forgot to add `>-1` to first two calls.

Answer (score 0):

The `|` in search string does not work like `or` operator. You should divide it into three calls like this:

```py
if text.find('bachelor') > -1 or text.find('ba/bs') > -1 or text.find('bs/ba') > -1:
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing:

```
bachelors = ["bachelor", "ba/bs", "bs/ba"]

if any(bachelor in text for bachelor in bachelors):
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a custom function that requires `.apply` (which will be quite slow), you can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for this. Also, you don't need [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to turn booleans into `1` and `0`; try using [`astype(int)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) instead.

```
df_jobs = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['job ba/bs', 'job bachelor', 
                                        'job bs/ba', 'job ba']})

df_jobs['bachelor'] = df_jobs.description.str.contains(
    'bachelor|ba/bs|bs/ba', regex=True).astype(int)

print(df_jobs)

    description  bachelor
0     job ba/bs         1
1  job bachelor         1
2     job bs/ba         1
3        job ba         0 

# note that the pattern does not look for match on simply "ba"!
```